# Dynamic DNS for subdomain using AWS & Route53

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I'm writing a dynamic DNS service which should return results based on a db query.

My DNS server is written in node.js and it queries the database for the actual IP.

My domain is hosted on Route53, but I'm not sure how to point all sub-subdomains to my server.

so basically, I have example.com registered under route53, and I would like to point all *.dyn.example.com to my DNS server (ec2 instance) so it will resolve it to the right IP.

I've tried to create a new name server entry, but route53 does not allow wildcard for it. I also have a lot of other subdomains there, which is why I want to only point *.dyn.example.com to my DNS server rather than *.example.com.

Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure an NS record for `dyn.example.com` on Route53 which points to the EC2 instance running your custom name server which would be authoritative for the domain `dyn.example.com`. Now DNS queries for hostnames under `dyn.example.com` would hit your EC2 instance. All other resource records would be on this EC2 name server so that it can respond to queries.

Something like this should work.

```
dyn.example.com.        172800  IN  NS  ec2.example.com.
```

You do not need a wild card entry for the NS record. You may need to add glue records if the hostname you have given to the EC2 instance is under `dyn.example.com`

You probably can just use the [Route53 API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) to create/modify/delete DNS records based on your application logic and use Route53 itself to host the zone, in which case you do not need to run a separate name server.